# How to find a coordinate by connecting the three coordinates lie on three sides of equilateral triangle.

Tags: geometry

Let's suppose i have an equilateral triangle abc having three coordinates A(40,60), B(70,30), C(50,80) as shown in figure.
[image: Image Location of coordinates on Triangle]

I want to find a coordinate which intersects with all the point let this coordinate be D(x,y) as shown in figure:
[image: Coordinate D(x,y) after connecting all other Coordinates]

Given that AD is parallel to bc, BD is parallel to ab, and DC is parallel to ac. 
Please help in finding coordinate D.

Comment: Needs more condition than what you have given us, for example, the slope of side $ab$.

Comment: abc is an equilateral triangle, so we can take angle between ab and bc as 60 degrees. I have only this information, regarding coordinates for abc. You can take any value for this if you want to explain your point. Please let me know if any further clarification you need.

Comment: Given the conditions, use the fact that the angels created for point D are 120 degrees.

Comment: Will it be valid in all the cases?